# Which memory metric does Openshift OOM Killer use

Tags: java, docker, openshift

We are running a set of Java applications in docker containers on OpenShift. On a regular basis we experience oom kills for our containers.

To analyse this issue we set up Instana and Grafana for monitoring. In Grafana we have graphs for each of our containers showing memory metrics e.g. JVM heap, memory.usage and memory.total_rss. From these graphs we know that the heap as well as the memory.total_rss of our containers is pretty stable on a certain level over a week. So we assume that we do not have a memory leak in our Java application. However, the memeory.total is constantly increasing over the time and after a couple of days it goes beyond the configured memory limit of the docker container. As far as we can see this doesn't cause Openshift to kill the container immediately but sooner or later it happens.

We increased the memory limit of all our containers and this seems to help since Openshift is not killing our containers that often anymore. However we still see in Grafana that the memeory.total is exceeding the configures memory limit of our containers significantly after a couple of days (rss memory is fine).

To better understand Openshifts OOM killer, does anybody know which memory metric Openshift takes into account to decide if a container has to be killed or not? Is the configured container memory limit related to the memory.usage or the memory.total_rss or something completely different?

Thanks for help in advance.